# How to use Rails console in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jupyter

I want to use Jupyter notebooks as my rails console, exactly like django-extensions allows via `shell_plus --notebook` in Django.

Any ideas how to do this?

I saw [this post](http://techlife.cookpad.com/entry/201510-jupyter-and-rails) which seems to be explaining how to do what I want, but I don't read Japanese or really understand what's going on here.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 8):

I created this gem to automatically do the things needed for running `rails c` on jupyter:

https://github.com/Yuki-Inoue/jupyter_on_rails

Add to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jupyter_on_rails'
gem 'ffi-rzmq'
```

run `bundle install`, and then run:

```
rake jupyter:notebook
```

`jupyter` is now running and will have a kernel named to your Rails app, and it'll automatically load the Rails app on initialization.

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
    require 'RAILS_ROOT_PATH/config/boot'
    require 'RAILS_ROOT_PATH/config/application'
    Rails.application.require_environment!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 4.2.6 and Jupyter 1.0.0.  With this configuration all you have to do is require your Rails application's `config/application`:

`require 'path/to/rails/application/config/application'`

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.1, ruby 2.2.5. While importing `application.rb` works, when I try to query one of my models, say `User`, I get an error `NameError: uninitialized constant User`